# Reading an excel with password protected sheet. While saving workbook password no longer stays

Tags: .net, vb.net, aspose, aspose-cells

Here I am opening an excel file. Excel has a sheet which is protected with a password.

```
myWorkBook = New Aspose.Cells.WorkbookDesigner
myWorkBook.Workbook = New Aspose.Cells.Workbook(inFileName)
```

After saving the sheet the worksheet remains protected but the password is lost and the sheet now can be modified without a password.

```
myWorkBook.Workbook.Save(outFileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to password it again after reading it.

```
 Globals.Sheet1.Protect(Password, AllowSorting:=True)
```

Comment: @nirajkasar how would you expect to know that? I don't think you can grab that kind of information, it definitely smells being able to grab passwords. Think you would have to create a new password or somehow have each sheet and it's password stored on a database so you can refer to it later.

Comment: Thank you guys for taking time to reply. I do not expect to know the password. I just expect it to carry forward the existing password when I create a copy of the file.

Comment: I am unable to find your issue, please check this link:  https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/832326/832326/showthread.aspx#832326

Comment: Awesome. Version change did the trick! Thank you @shakeel! Saved my day!

Comment: @nirajkasar thanks for your feedback. It is good to know that latest version has resolved your problem.